# Ubuntu - Windows 10 - MBR

Tags: windows-10, mbr

I have installed Ubuntu along side Windows 10 but need to remove it and install Fedora.

Am I able to fix the MBR before removing the Ubuntu partition?

I realise this question looks like so many others, but its slightly different and I cannot find an answer elsewhere.

Basically I have goosed my MBR numerous times in the past and this time I wanted to ensure all will run smooth.

The solutions I see are to first fire up Windows remove the partition, insert the Windows recovery media and fix the MBR. As mentioned before I have ended up with a dead laptop and had to wipe and restart.

So am I able to first fix the MBR while Ubuntu is still on, then fire up Windows and at this time delete the partition?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I wonder why you want to "fix" your MBR that early in the process. As I understand Fedora will probably write it's own flavor of MBR to your disk while installing. This then will (I guess) allow you to boot into a bootmanager to choose to boot either Windows or Fedora.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @MadMike. I will look at my formatting in the future.

Comment: No Problem. Also edits aren't meant to criticize, just to (hopefully) make things easier for the next person to read. You can easily rollback any edits other people make.

Comment: @MadMike I was unsure how doing it that way would affect my system. As mentioned I have struggled with damaged MBR in the past. I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that it would cause the least headaches if I first got my system back to just Windows and then went about installing Fedora much the same as I did for Ubuntu.

Comment: I realise this MadMike and I prefer your edits as they do add more clarity to the reader.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply install GRUB to your disk (not to any of the partitions) and that will overwrite the MBR with working GRUB files.

A detailed guide on this can be found here:
[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/q/88384/367990)

However, this is not necessary as you're going to install Fedora anyway. It will install GRUB during the installation anyway, so that should fix it as well.

If you really want to first remove Ubuntu and GRUB and restore the Windows bootloader though, you have to follow this: [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/q/133533/367990)

Comment: Thanks for your response. However,  it appears to be the reverse of what I require. I don't want to overwrite MBR with Grub. I wanted to remove Ubuntu and leave Windows as the lone OS as before so I can then start the process again and add Fedora along side Windows.

Comment: If you add Fedora again, that will also install GRUB again and overwrite the MBR. So I think there's no advantage in installing the Windows bootloader to the MBR first. However, if you really want to first remove Ubuntu and GRUB and restore the Windows bootloader, you have to follow this: http://askubuntu.com/q/133533/367990

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks again. I will attempt to do as your answer states. Will give the tick once done.

Comment: Actually the link you provided is exactly what I want to do. If you want to post your link as a new answer I will accept that and give it the tick.

Comment: I added it to this answer.